# How can I delay a jQuery .blur function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onblur

I'm using this code to validate an input field, but I don't want it to pull the text from the field until half a second after the field loses focus.  How can I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#group_id").blur(function()
    {
    $("#gmsgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn("slow");
            $.post("group_availability.php",{ group_id:$(this).val() } ,function(data)
            {
             if(data=='invalid')
              {
                $("#gmsgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
                {
                  $(this).html('Please enter a valid Group ID').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                });     
              }
              else
              {
            $("#gmsgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()  //start fading the messagebox
            {
              $(this).html('Group ID available').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1);    
            });
             }
            }); 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
$("#group_id").blur(function() {
    $("#gmsgbox").delay(500).queue(function() {
        $("#gmsgbox").removeClass().addClass(//etc...
```

Comment: `$("#group_id").blur(function(){$(this).delay(300).queue(function(){//The code you want to execute after delay $("#gmsgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking..).fadeIn("slow");}); });`

Comment: You are missing `$("#gmsgbox").` before `removeClass()`

Comment: @David Sorry about that.. fixed it.

Comment: Sandeepan, that's great, except for one problem.  The input field now only validates once; it doesn't recheck after changes are made to the text in that field.

Comment: Emmett, for some reason that doesn't work.  However, Sandeepan's does.  There is only a very minor difference between your answers.  However, I have the problem noted in my comment above.

Comment: @David are you getting any errors after first time? Is the post method firing? Check in firebug , put some `alert()` after `$("#group_id").blur(function() {` and `$("#gmsgbox").delay(500).queue(function() {`

Comment: I threw in the alerts.  The one after `$("#gmsgbox").delay(500).queue(function() {` doesn't appear but once.  Post isn't firing after the first time.

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to add `$(this).clearQueue();` near the end.

Comment: great! I guessed that. so is it needed to explicitly write `clearQueue()` even if the things after the delay executed?

Comment: Sandeepan, I believe that's the case.

Comment: I am not sure about that. As per http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/ clearQueue does this - "Remove from the queue all items that have not yet been run." So, you needed to `clearQueue` probably because something queued did not actually complete execution. Anyways congratulations on fixing the bug!

Answer (score 0):

Try By `setInterval(), clearInterval()`